# Multi-module maven project: Generate EAR with shaded artifacts

Tags: java, maven, ear, maven-shade-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

I have a multi-module project and one of the modules should create an EAR out of the other modules artifacts. To make things more interesting, these other 4 artifacts have to be shaded into 2 artifacts:

```
super-pom
|-- ear module
|-- ejb1
|-- ejb2
|-- web1
|-- web2
```

What it creates is an EAR containing ejb2-shaded, web2-shaded AND ej1, web1 (which are included in the shaded versions!).
Oddly enough, if I run maven manually in each module and in the ear-module in the end, I get what I wanted.

What I can't figure out is, how the super-pom sneaks these artifacts into the EAR. Event `maven package -X` only lists the right artifacts in the ear cration step:

```
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact type mappings ...
[DEBUG] Initializing JBoss configuration if necessary ...
[DEBUG] Initializing ear execution context
[DEBUG] Resolving ear modules ...
[DEBUG] Resolving ear module[ejb:com.mycomp:ejb2]
[DEBUG] Resolving ear module[war:com.mycomp:web2]
[DEBUG] Resolving ear module[jar:org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam]
[INFO] Generating application.xml
```

Some simplified poms, starting with the super-pom:

```
<artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>ejb1</module>
    <module>web1</module>
    <module>ejb2</module>
    <module>web2</module>
    <module>ear</module>
</modules>
```

ear-pom:

```
<artifactId>ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<parent>
    ...
    <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
    ...
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        ...
        <artifactId>ejb2</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        ...
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        ...
        <artifactId>web2</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        ...
    </dependency>
    <!-- Little "trick" to avoid listing all shared deps from WAR. To use skinyWar, 
            deps to be shared via EAR/lib must be explicitly listed here. Including the 
            POM let's maven deal with this -->
    <dependency>
        ...
        <artifactId>web2</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        ...
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Tell Maven we are using Java EE 6 -->
            <version>6</version>
            <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
            <!-- See maven docs; Necessary because we CAN'T have 2 jboss-seam.jars 
                in the same EAR -->
            <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
            <initializeInOrder>true</initializeInOrder>
            <modules>
                <ejbModule>
                    <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ejb2</artifactId>
                </ejbModule>
                <webModule>
                    <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>web2</artifactId>
                    <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                </webModule>

                <jarModule>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-seam</artifactId>
                    <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                </jarModule>
            </modules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

ejb2-pom:

```
<artifactId>ejb2</artifactId>
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
<parent>
    ...
    <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
    ...
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        ...
        <artifactId>ejb1</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
        ...
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <promoteTransitiveDependencies>true</promoteTransitiveDependencies>
              <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                  <include>com.mycomp:ejb1</include>
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

web2-pom:

```
<artifactId>web2</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    ...
    <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
    ...
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        ...
        <artifactId>web1</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
        ...
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <promoteTransitiveDependencies>true</promoteTransitiveDependencies>
              <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                  <include>com.mycomp:web1</include>
                </includes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I get what I want if I explicitly exclude the modules in the ear-pom. But that's not quite the solution I was hoping for.

Comment: Why are you trying to shade artifacts? What is the advantage?

Comment: I'm converting a legacy (ant built) project. There is a generic and a project-specific part. I can't deploy an EAR with 2 wars and 2 jars, because some of the mandatory config files are in the project-specific part. Not my idea, I just have to deal with this somehow.

Comment: Excuse me?! Watch your tone! You have absolutely now idea about the status of the project or the structure of my company. This is not some school exercise, I'm trying to update an almost a decade old application with loads of old baggage. I can't just sit down and change everything at once, I don't have the time and budget for that. Refactoring such things is done gradually. And the first step is to modernize the build to make it quicker and more reliable. If you have nothing constructive to add, you are free to read other threads.

Comment: I'm sorry..for that...